# Get UISwitch state/value in UITests

Tags: ios, swift, coded-ui-tests, uiswitch, uitest

I'm working with a `UISwitch`, and I'm currently coding the UI Tests.
The problem is that I don't know how to get the Switch value/state in these tests.
In the program code, I can use `mySwitch.isOn` that returns `true` or `false`, but in the UI Tests I don't know how to get this value.

A little help in english correction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let mySwitch = app.switches["mySwitch"]
let isOn = mySwitch.value as! String
```

The current `UISwitch.isOn` value should then be reflected in the `isOn` variable above.

Comment: It doesn't works: "Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1036e2d60) to 'NSNumber' (0x102cef4a8)"

Comment: @JosepBernadEspinosa So try as a string instead: `mySwitch.value as! String` (and print the result please). These UI tests APIs can be tricky :(

Comment: @JosepBernadEspinosa Cool! Please check if my latest edit finally gets you the `Bool` you deserve :)

Comment: No man, it doesn't: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @JosepBernadEspinosa Ok, no problem. Looks like we are stuck with the string for now...